# Android share deep link url using whatsapp and open my app when click deep link

Tags: android, whatsapp, deep-linking

I am sharing some data using whatsapp, and I want to open a specific activity in my app when user press deep link from whatsapp

I have the following schema

```
myapp://openapp?type=banner&id=10
```

whatsapp share the link as a normal text not as url and also I can't open my app when user press it

can anyone help please ?

**EDIT**

this is my sharing method

```
public static void openWhatsApp(Context mContext) {

        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
        try {

            Intent whatsAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            whatsAppIntent.setType("text/plain");

            String text = "myapp://openapp?type=banner&id=10";

            PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            whatsAppIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

            whatsAppIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsAppIntent, mContext.getString(R.string.share_with)));

       } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the referral linking from these link http://technology.jana.com/2014/11/11/tracking-referrers-for-your-android-app/comment-page-1/

Comment: is it possible to redirect to play store if app not installed using same link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible. It may be that WhatsApp only highlights links with certain protocols (i.e. http, https). In this case, you could go for a work-around if you are depending on this feature:

Let the user share a link to `http://your-server.com/forward?type=banner&id=10`

On `your-server.com`, you re-direct the user within the `forward` file (or via server configuration) to `myapp://openapp?type=banner&id=10`.

Of course this is not pretty, but browsers can handle these app-links. This will not be pretty, since the user will at first open a browser to process your http link, from which the user will be redirected.

Comment: My friend [iOS Developer] told me that he is using "whatsapp://send?text=" and it works with him, but when I try it nothing happen.

Comment: `whatsapp://send?text=...` will share the text with a WhatsApp user if I'm not mistaken, it is not supposed to highlight your custom-protocol URI within a WhatsApp chat.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem I'm facing atm.
Using Android App-Links seems to be the correct solution.
From the docs:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#request-verify

## The difference between deep links and app links:

- A **deep link** is an intent filter that allows users to directly enter a specific activity in your Android app. (You tried to use this one, but Whatsapp doesn't recognize this as a link)
- An **Android App Link** is a deep link based on your website URL that has been verified to belong to your website. (This is a normal http(s) link, it should be recognized as thus everywhere)