# How to properly create an Intent to refer like Tez?

Tags: android, android-intent, invite

In my app i have to add an intent to share my app. I looked through Tez, which shares the app icon along with a text which contains a hyperlink. How to achieve this?[image]

Comment: what is `Tez`? It is not a part of Android SDK.

Comment: i am not saying tez is a part of android sdk, i meant how did they sent that intent

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Tez is a google app for transferring money.

Comment: This post is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175055/android-share-deep-link-url-using-whatsapp-and-open-my-app-when-click-deep-link

Comment: None of the answers work. I tried all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void prepareShareIntent(Bitmap bmp) {
        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(bmp); // see previous remote images section
        // Construct share intent as described above based on bitmap

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.share_app)  );
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Opportunity"));

    }

private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one..

```
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent();
    intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent1.setType("image/*");
    intent1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Name");
    intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download the app from google play store now - "+ APP_STORE_URL);
    intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Share"));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

this will works : put image file and text box in share intent

Answer (score 1):

It look like you want to create an referrer links for which try using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android?authuser=1)  firebase service.Once you have got your referrer URL ready.Create an intent as follow to share it.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectText);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, "Hey!Checkout this app "+ APP_STORE_URL); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Invite Friends"));
```

**Note:**If you are using dynamic links you can add your app icon in the social meta tags param

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(); 
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello" + REFERRAL_URL);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));`
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code into your toolbar/menu

```
    try {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject");
    String text = "\nYour description";
    text = text + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apppackagename \n\n";
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose "));
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
    //e.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");

    /**This is the image to share**/
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);


    OutputStream outstream;
    try {
        outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
        outstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR_BODY_TEXT_HERE");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

I've tested the above code, it works as per your requirement.

**PS:** You need to have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Be sure to include it and handle it ***according to SDK's***.

Answer (score 1):

> > This code will share both the files together

```
    ArrayList<Uri> myFilesUriList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    myFilesUriList.add(); // add your image path as uri
    myFilesUriList.add(); // add your text file path as uri

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myFilesUriList);
    startActivity(intent);
```

> > ```
> >  This code will share both the files Separately
> > First share the file then on Activity Result, share text Separately
> > ```

```
        ArrayList<Uri> uriArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        uriArrayList.add(); // add your image path as uri

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriArrayList);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 156);

        @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 156) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""); //"Subject here"
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "shareBody ");
            sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share text via.."));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's URL Meta Data. These meta data is returned as response from server.

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="San Roque 2014 Pollos">
<meta property="og:title" content="San Roque 2014 Pollos" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Programa de fiestas" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="http://pollosweb.wesped.es/programa_pollos/play.png">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="1440432930" />
```

[Showing Thumbnail for link in WhatsApp || og:image meta-tag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Read the image which you want to share
Step 2 - Store that image in your external storage
Step 3 - share via intent

```
// Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.launcher); // your image
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bitmapUri = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bitmapUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (bitmapUri != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I am inviting you to join our app. A simple and secure app developed by us. https://www.google.co.in/");
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share my app"));
    }
}
```

Note -  Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest. Ask runtime permission on Android 6.0 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for ***deep linking*** to your app

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Or if you want links to your app across platforms you can check out ***Firebase dynamic links***
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int applicationNameId = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;
final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(applicationNameId));
String text = "Install this cool application: ";
String link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName;
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text + " " + link);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share link:"));
```

if you want to share your other apps from your dev. account you can do something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer? 
id=Your_Publisher_Name"));
startActivity(intent);
```