# How to have app links (Android) url with no "www" & "https" prefix

Tags: android, react-native, ios-universal-links, applinks

I have a working app link feature on my android app built using React native. The issue is that the current link looks something like this https://www.example.xyz/something/ and the following is the intent filter used for the same

```
  <data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="www.example.xyz"
        android:pathPrefix="/something"
  />
```

on clicking on the above given link it opens the app. But I would like to know how I can remove prefix "www" & "https" from the app link so that it still opens the app. I have tried removing the "www" & "https" from the  tag mentioned above but all it does is, not open the app. I went through the documentation here https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking
Nothing mentions there on how to do it and in fact all of the example links mentioned over there has "www" in them.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450789/android-deep-linking-with-custom-uri) - **as in Answers**, you can find the **example** of what you need.

You can also take a look at https://www.flipandroid.com/deep-link-no-funciona-en-chrome-para-android.html (but you would need to translate this site)